# Using a list of lists by saving it on a text file and importing it when using it. Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I'm coding a program that's based around the idea of booking cinema tickets, currently it works fine however I'd like the program to save the booked seats when it closes so I can have different screens and restart the program and have the same bookings. I planned on doing this by saving it to a text file each time it's used however I have had problems finding a good method to do this.

This is what my list looks like

```
seats = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

seats = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# Save to seats.json
with open('seats.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(seats, file)

# Load from seats.json
with open('seats.json') as file:
    loaded_seats = json.load(file)

print(loaded_seats)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to put your data set, which in your case is seats into a pandas df and save it to csv from there. Later you can just load the data set from the already saved csv.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(seats)


   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

You can play with it as you like its easy using pandas, look at the pandas doc for more info
link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The task of converting structured data to simple byte sequence that can be written to a file or transmitted is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Python offers several methods. [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) seems to be a good choice for this case. It is very simple and the output is human readable, so you could verify your program. There are some limitations regarding the supported data types, that you should be familiar with.